# How can I use libraries in IntelliJ IDEA's scratch files?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to experiment with [Jsoup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup) functions in the scratch files, but all I get is

```
package org.jsoup does not exist
```

The library is imported both as a local, and as global one. I am really puzzled on how to make this work.

Comment: Did you add it in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency?

Comment: Well, I did everything in the paragraph "add a new dependency" on this page, it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better way, but I usually edit the run configuration for my scratch file, go to "Use classpath of module" and choose a project with the required dependencies.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks! I have no idea, why is this information is so kind of hard to find...